# TextView not showing up when I add it to LinearLayout

Tags: android, kotlin, android-linearlayout

I try to create a cardView that contains an image and beside that image I want to add two lines of text (vertically stacked on each other). Below is the code I have written to do this (the function returns a cardView). However, in my cardView nothing is appearing. If I remove the linearLayout and the textViews than I get a card which shows the imageView. So I assume I'm doing something wrong with the way I set the linearLayout on my textViews or the way I add my linearLayout to my tableRow.

```
 private fun constructCardView(header: String, info: String) : CardView {
    val cardView = CardView(this)

    cardView.setPaddingRelative(5,0,0,0)
    cardView.radius = 10F

    val tableLayout = TableLayout(this)
    val layoutParams = TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1.0f)
    tableLayout.layoutParams = layoutParams

    val tableRow = TableRow(this)
    val tableRowParams = TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f)
    tableRow.layoutParams = tableRowParams


    val imageView = ImageView(this)
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_restaurant_black_24dp)
    imageView.minimumHeight = 10
    imageView.minimumWidth = 10

    val linearLayout = LinearLayout(this)
    val linearLayoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
    linearLayoutParams.setMargins(3,3,3,3)
    linearLayout.layoutParams = linearLayoutParams
    linearLayout.orientation = LinearLayout.VERTICAL

    val textViewHeader = TextView(this)
    val textViewHeaderLayoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
    textViewHeaderLayoutParams.setMargins(0, 0, 5, 0)
    textViewHeader.layoutParams = textViewHeaderLayoutParams
    textViewHeader.text = header
    textViewHeader.textSize = 20F

    val textViewInfo = TextView(this)
    val textViewInfoLayoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
    textViewInfoLayoutParams.setMargins(5, 0, 5, 0)
    textViewInfo.text = info
    textViewInfo.textSize = 12F
    textViewInfo.layoutParams = textViewInfoLayoutParams

    linearLayout.addView(textViewHeader)
    linearLayout.addView(textViewInfo)

    tableRow.addView(imageView)
    tableRow.addView(linearLayout)


    tableLayout.addView(tableRow)
    cardView.addView(tableLayout)
    cardView.requestLayout()

    return cardView
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is there a reason to not use xml and inflate the view?

Comment: Have you tried placing your `ImageView` and the textviews' `LinearLayout` in a parent horizontal `LinearLayout` inside the row?

Comment: I tried that but it didnt worked.

Answer (score 0):

Just to offer an alternative if using xml is an option, as I think it saves up many many lines of code to get the same job done.

You probably want to use `LinearLayout` instead of the `Tablelayout` to stack things vertically or horizontally, as a more versatile approach. For example I used the `layout_weight` property to define how the rows are split in percentage.

Create an xml file in the `layouts` folder:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

       <ImageView android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.4"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/header"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/info"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Then in code:

```
private fun constructCardView(header: String, info: String) : CardView {
    val cardView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.cardview, parent, false)
    cardView.header.text = header
    cardView.info.text = info
    return cardView as CardView
}
```